# \mbox does not draw a box inside align*

Tags: math-mode, boxes, align, mhchem, mathtools

`\mbox` doesn't work inside `align*`:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{mhchem}

    \begin{align*} 
    \ce{K_w} &= \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -\log ( \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} ) \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= - ( \log \ce{[H3O+]} + \log \ce{[OH^-]} )  & \text{(Using log law for RHS.)}\\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} + - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    \mbox{ \ce{pK_w} &= \ce{pH} + \ce{pOH} }\\
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\mbox` should not span across the alignment operator `&` in the `align` (or `align*`) environment. So you need `\mbox{...} &= \mbox{...}`. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.  Even if it did, is there a less awkward solution than splitting up my box command?  I want to do it to emphasize a particular result which should be remembered.  I thought of using `empheq` but that seems pretty heavy-handed; I just want that one line boxed in the least obstrusive way possible as far as the code I have to add.

Comment: Unlike the operator p equilibrium constants such as Kw are simple variables and should simply be typeset as such, i.e., in math mode and in italics $K_w$. For reference see page 58 of IUPAC Green Book (third edition).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you are trying to place a box around the last equation. One way to do that is to use `Aboxed` from the `mathtools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*} 
    \ce{K_w} &= \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -\log ( \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} ) \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= - ( \log \ce{[H3O+]} + \log \ce{[OH^-]} )  & \text{(Using log law for RHS.)}\\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} + - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    \Aboxed{ \ce{pK_w} &= \ce{pH} + \ce{pOH} }
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While it is true that the descriptions of `mbox` tell you that it creates a box just wide enough to hold the text, this is not a box that gets drawn. It is a virtual "box" in the TeX sense that does not get split across lines.

Comment: Just the simple elegant solution I was after, thanks Peter!

Answer (score 3):

If you want the highlighting of the equation to be a bit more subtle, you can modify the `\Aboxed` command provided by the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). For instance, in the example below, the equation of interest is emphasized with a 15% black background (alternatives is also possible, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@Aboxed}{\boxed{#1#2}}{\colorbox{black!15}{$#1#2$}}{}{}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \begin{align*} 
    \ce{K_w} &= \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -\log ( \ce{[H3O+][OH^-]} ) \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= - ( \log \ce{[H3O+]} + \log \ce{[OH^-]} )  & \text{(Using log law for RHS.)}\\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    -\log \ce{K_w} &= -  \log \ce{[H3O+]} + - \log \ce{[OH^-]} \\
    \Aboxed{ \ce{pK_w} &= \ce{pH} + \ce{pOH} }\\
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Modified \Aboxed]

Modification of `\Aboxed` is performed using `\patchcmd{<command>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}` (provided by the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)). Specifically, the `\boxed{#1#2}` command (that boxes the left- `#1` and right-hand side `#2` of the equation in `align`) is replaced with `\colorbox{<color>}{$#1#2$}` allowing for a coloured box. Colour choices is supported by means of [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor).

Comment: It should be `\colorbox{black!15}{$#1#2$}` or the alignment will not be as desired.

Comment: @egreg: It was too early in the morning too see that; thanks! :)

Comment: Great solution! What are the two arguments in e. g. **\boxed{#1#2}**? Is the **&** separating the two arguments? I have never seen this before.