# How to box two lines inside align*

Tags: math-mode, boxes, align

I asked a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30214/mbox-does-not-draw-a-box-inside-align) today except it was targeted at one particular line inside the `align*` environment. Now I want to enclose two lines. The failed attempt below makes my intention clear:

```
\begin{align*}
\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b} &= \ce{K_w}\\
-\log(\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
 -( \log(\ce{K_a}) + \log(\ce{K_b}) ) &= -\log\ce{K_w} & \text{(Using log law for LHS.)} \\
 - \log(\ce{K_a}) - \log(\ce{K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
\fbox{
 \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w}\\
&=14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\\
\end{minpage}
}
\end{align*}
```

`\Aboxed` from `mathtools` pkg was a great solution, you didn't have to specify mandatory parameters and it was as simple as `Aboxed{ }` - alas it only works for single line boxes.

As for `\Aboxed` I don't want to be asked how wide the box should be - it should be automatically determined.

As usual, I prefer predefined solutions, and less obstrusive code to achieve the desired effect.  The less clutter the better.

P.S. By the way, [this manual](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#makebox) seems to suggest `\mbox`, and anologously `\fbox` ought to draw frames around the enclosed content.  Previously I could not get `\mbox` to display visible frames...

Comment: `\mbox` was *never* designed to draw frames.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the mandatory width argument for `minipage` - does anyone know why it's still not working?  I'd like to try and get it to work the way above since the solutions below are far too advanced for me for the time being...

Comment: @ptrcao: Honestly, I don't know. This must be connected in some way to the implementation of the `align` environment and the internal plumbings of `(La)TeX`. That's a bit of black magic for me too. :)

Comment: @ptrcao: A very simple (and very ugly) approach would be to break down the `align` environment into two parts, one that is going to be framed and the other that is not. Then you can put the 'framable' content into a `\parbox` and frame the `\parbox`. But here again, you must specify manually the width of the box.
**NOTE**: I deliberately didn't post this as an answer, because it's just too ugly...

Comment: @Count Zero: I was reading about empheq earlier, perhaps you know about that? There must be a predefined way, a package which can accomplish this neatly; I simply can't believe there wouldn't be considering how basic this problem is...

Comment: @ptrcao: I took a look at [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh). Reading the documentation, it is clear to me that it is way more difficult to achieve what you want with that one than with the answers already given. Trust me, I've been in a similar bind when I had to typeset some ugly colored frame around section titles (I had to follow a strict template). The `titlesec` package did the trick, but I spent a week until I figured it out. I guess I'm still pretty far from being a (La)TeX wizzard...

Answer (score 5):

Here an inspiration with `tikz`

(everyone is welcome to modify the example -- i am not familiar with `tikz`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{markeq}
\setcounter{markeq}{0}
\newcommand*\bmarkeq{%
   \stepcounter{markeq}%
   \tikz[remember picture]\node(startframe-\themarkeq){\strut};}
\newcommand*\emarkeq{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node (endframe-\themarkeq){\strut};
     \draw[,red,opacity=0.8] (startframe-\themarkeq.north) rectangle (endframe-\themarkeq.south);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b} &= \ce{K_w}\\
-\log(\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
 -( \log(\ce{K_a}) + \log(\ce{K_b}) ) &= -\log\ce{K_w} & \text{(Using log law for LHS.)} \\
 - \log(\ce{K_a}) - \log(\ce{K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
\bmarkeq\ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w}\\
&=14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

With the very great idea of egreg you get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{markeq}
\setcounter{markeq}{0}

\newcommand{\pstrut}[1]{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width0pt #1 \fboxsep}
\newcommand*\bmarkeq{\stepcounter{markeq}%
  \tikz[remember picture]\node(startframe-\themarkeq){\pstrut{height}};%
  \kern\fboxsep}
\newcommand*\emarkeq{\kern\fboxsep
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (endframe-\themarkeq){\pstrut{depth}};
    \draw[,red,opacity=0.8] (startframe-\themarkeq.north) 
      rectangle (endframe-\themarkeq.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b} &= \ce{K_w}\\
-\log(\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
 -( \log(\ce{K_a}) + \log(\ce{K_b}) ) &= -\log\ce{K_w} & \text{(Using log law for LHS.)} \\
 - \log(\ce{K_a}) - \log(\ce{K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
\bmarkeq\ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w}\\
&=14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq
\end{align*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's an attempt that mimics the approach taken by `\Aboxed` from the [`mathtools` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{textcomp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp
\usepackage{siunitx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylen}% Length of widest element on left of &
\settowidth{\mylen}{$\displaystyle \ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b}$}
\addtolength\mylen{\fboxsep}%
\addtolength\mylen{\fboxrule}%

\begin{align*}
  \ce{K_a $\times$ K_b} &= \ce{K_w} \\
  -\log(\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
  -( \log(\ce{K_a}) + \log(\ce{K_b}) ) &= -\log\ce{K_w} & \text{(Using log law for LHS.)} \\
  - \log(\ce{K_a}) - \log(\ce{K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
 \kern\mylen & \kern-\mylen\fbox{$%
   \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}%
     \ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b} = \ce{pK_w} \\[\jot]%
     \phantom{\ce{pK_a} + \ce{pK_b}} = 14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\textcelsius})}
 \end{array}$}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Emphasizing two equations in align*]

Answer (score 2):

One can also use the `empheq` package. For example

```
\begin{empheq}[box=\fbox]{align}
        a&=b\\
        E&=mc^2 + \int_a^b x dx
\end{empheq}
```

will produce the following output :
[image]

More info is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/empheq) or in the [pdf documentation](http://ctan.triasinformatica.nl/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/empheq.pdf) of the `empheq` package.

EDIT: It seems like this package only allows boxing all the align environment and not the two last lines for example. I'm not sure however. 
Please note that I don't delete this answer because of its simplicity.

Comment: This suggestion may not suits with the OP's requirement, hence `empheq` will draw a box for the whole equation not the part of an equation...

Comment: @MadyYuvi That's what I precised in the "Edit" part of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30251/73317) that:

- doesn't rely on luck<sup>1</sup> to look right (try setting `inner sep=0` in the `\node` options, printing the reference point of each TikZ picture or simply changing the `\vrule` width in the second code sample to something non-zero like `1pt` and you'll see :-);
- respects the height of the first boxed line and the depth of the last boxed line (this is the tricky part!);
- allows one to tune each of the six interesting lengths (four inside and two outside the frame), like this:

```latex
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep}{...}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep}{...}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep}{...}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep}{...}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep}{...}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignRightSep}{...}%
```

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{markeq}

% Spacing above the top rule and below the bottom rule of our frames
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep}
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep}

% Spacing inside the frames
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep}
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep}
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep}
\newlength{\boxPartOfAlignRightSep}

\newcommand*{\bmarkeq}{%
  \noalign{%
    \nointerlineskip
    \kern
      \dimexpr \boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep + \boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep
               + \jot \relax
    \vbox to 0pt
      {\hbox to \hsize{\tikzmark{aboveLine-\themarkeq}\hss}\vss}%
    \nointerlineskip}%
  \tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (before-\themarkeq) {};%
}

\newcommand*{\emarkeq}{%
  \tikz[remember picture] \coordinate (after-\themarkeq) {};%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (upperLeftCorner) at
      ([shift={(-\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep,\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep)}]
       before-\themarkeq |- {pic cs:aboveLine-\themarkeq});

    \coordinate (lowerRightCorner) at
      ([shift={(\boxPartOfAlignRightSep,-\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep)}]
       after-\themarkeq |- {pic cs:belowLine-\themarkeq});

    \draw[red,opacity=0.8] (upperLeftCorner) rectangle (lowerRightCorner);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  %
  % Insert an empty line in the alignment in order to be able to put vertical
  % material before it (in particular a zero height, zero depth \vbox
  % containing a \tikzmark that tells us where the bottom of the just-finished
  % line is located).
  \\
  \noalign{%
    \nointerlineskip
    \vbox to 0pt{\hbox to \hsize{\tikzmark{belowLine-\themarkeq}\hss}\vss}%
    \stepcounter{markeq}%
    \nointerlineskip
    % Insert “after skip” and compensate for the empty line (maybe imperfect?)
    \kern \dimexpr \boxPartOfAlignAfterSep + \boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep
                   -\baselineskip + \jot \relax}%
  \null\hfill                                   % this is the empty line
}

% Test material that gets repeated in every align* env (used to make the
% repeated examples shorter).
\newcommand*{\startMaterial}{%
  \ce{K_a $\times$ K_b} &= \ce{K_w}\\
-\log(\ce{K_a $\times$ K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
 -( \log(\ce{K_a}) + \log(\ce{K_b}) ) &= -\log\ce{K_w} & \text{(Using log law for LHS.)} \\
 - \log(\ce{K_a}) - \log(\ce{K_b}) &= -\log\ce{K_w}\\
\bmarkeq\ce{pK_a} +}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep}{0pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignRightSep}{0pt}%
Let's start with tight settings (all six tunable lengths set to 0pt):
\begin{align*}
\startMaterial
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w} \\
            &= 14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq
\end{align*}
Text after the alignment. \lipsum[1][1-3]

Same thing with lines following the boxed line(s):
\begin{align*}
\startMaterial
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w}\\
            &= 14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq\\
            &= \text{whatever}
\end{align*}

{%
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}%
Same thing with more spacing between two consecutive lines of the alignment
(\verb|\jot| set to \verb|10pt|):
\begin{align*}
\startMaterial
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w}\\
            &= 14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq\\
            &= \text{whatever}
\end{align*}%
}
\lipsum[2][1-8]                 % fill the first page (for the screenshots...)

The height of the first boxed line and the depth of the last boxed line are
perfectly respected by our frame:
\begin{align*}
  \startMaterial
  \vrule width 0.4pt height 20pt depth 0pt\relax
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w} \\
            &= \vrule width 0.4pt height 0pt depth 10pt\relax
               14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq\\
            &= \text{whatever}
\end{align*}

\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignRightSep}{3pt}%
Now, with all six tunable lengths set to 3pt:
\begin{align*}
  \startMaterial
  \vrule width 0.4pt height 20pt depth 0pt\relax
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w} \\
            &= \vrule width 0.4pt height 0pt depth 10pt\relax
               14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq\\
            &= \text{whatever}
\end{align*}

\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep}{3pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep}{6pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep}{2pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignAfterSep}{4pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignLeftSep}{4pt}%
\setlength{\boxPartOfAlignRightSep}{8pt}%
Finally, with funky values for the six tunable lengths:\\*[1ex]\hspace*{3em}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\ttfamily\textbackslash}l@{\hspace{2em}}l}
  boxPartOfAlignOuterBeforeSep & 3pt\\
  boxPartOfAlignOuterAfterSep & 6pt\\
  boxPartOfAlignBeforeSep & 2pt\\
  boxPartOfAlignAfterSep & 4pt\\
  boxPartOfAlignLeftSep & 4pt\\
  boxPartOfAlignRightSep & 8pt\\
\end{tabular}
%
\begin{align*}
  \startMaterial
  \ce{pK_b} &= \ce{pK_w} \\
            &= 14.00 \text{ (at \SI{25}{\celsius})}\emarkeq\\
            &= \text{whatever}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

---

First page:

[image]

---

Second page:

[image]

With a minor change:

```
\newcommand*{\emarkeq}{%

  (...)

    \draw[blue, opacity=0.8, rounded corners]
      (upperLeftCorner) rectangle (lowerRightCorner);
  \end{tikzpicture}%

  (...)

}
```

one can obtain:

### [image]

**Footnote:**

1. Or rather, on the default value of `inner sep` for TikZ nodes.