# How to make a box around an equation in align-environment

Tags: align, boxes

I would like to draw a frame around one equation to point it out. I used

```
\fbox{...}
```

but it didn't work out.
Here is a minimal example where I tried it. Any package suggestions?

```
\documentclass[
    german,
    paper=a4,
    ]{scrbook}              %KOMA-
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .} \\ 
Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the frame around *both* lines?

Comment: Related: [How to box two lines inside `align*`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30250/5764)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `\Aboxed` command from `mathtools` package does what you want.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[
    german,
    paper=a4,
    ]{scrbook}              %KOMA-
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}} \\ 
\Aboxed{Nu_\text{m}        &= \frac{\alpha_m \, L}{\lambda}    \text{ \quad .}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to increase padding in \Aboxed?

Comment: Use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}` and `\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.4pt}` in the preamble to change the padding and width of the rule in `\Aboxed{}`

Comment: When boxing only a portion of a line, this adds a lot of margin before (left of) the box. Is there a way to remove this?