# \boxed command with included ampersand character not working in \align environment. Why?

Tags: align, amsmath

Greetings LaTeX Masters!

In the code below, I'm trying to align the solution steps on the equal sign. The alignment works until I get to the final step where I draw a box around the solution. This line of code doesn't draw the box:

`\boxed{x&=2}` and crashes the compiler.

Without the `&`, the solution box doesn't align.

[![Mis-aligned solution box][1]][1]

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Trapezoids: Median line formula\\

%\setcounter{equation}{2}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\jot}{8pt}
    \begin{aligned}
    Median &= \dfrac{1}{2}(top + bottom)\\
    3x+1&=\dfrac{(2x+1)+(2x+5)}{2}\\
    2\cdot (3x+1)&=\Biggl(\dfrac{(2x+1)+(2x+5)}{2}\Biggr) \cdot \dfrac{2}{1}\\
    6x+2&=4x+6\\
    6x&=4x+4\\
    2x&=4\\
  \boxed{x=2}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKBHo.png
````

Comment: not specific to boxed you can not use `{...}` around a `&` in any tex alignment

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you! So can you please suggest a way to get the solution box to align on the equal sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How to make a box around an equation in align-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193242/how-to-make-a-box-around-an-equation-in-align-environment)

You can't use directly stuff like `\yourcommand{a & b}` or LaTeX will think that the `&` symbol might be use for something else inside the `\yourcommand` macro. For instance, `\yourcommand` could be a shortcut to create an array.

You can use `\Aboxed{…}` from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

Trapezoids: Median line formula\\

\begin{align}
  Median &= \dfrac{1}{2}(top + bottom)\\
  3x+1&=\dfrac{(2x+1)+(2x+5)}{2}\\
  2\cdot (3x+1)&=\Biggl(\dfrac{(2x+1)+(2x+5)}{2}\Biggr) \cdot \dfrac{2}{1}\\
  6x+2&=4x+6\\
  6x&=4x+4\\
  2x&=4\\
  \Aboxed{x&=2}  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much for providing a solution I never would have found on my own! Question marked "solved"

Comment: @SiuslawMath By the way, you might prefer to simply use `\begin{align}` instead of nesting `equation` and `aligned`.

Comment: So I removed ```\begin{equation}``` and ```\end{equation} as suggested (assuming I followed instructions correctly). But now I get a "not in math mode" error. Note: The mwe code has been revised to reflect this change.

Comment: @toabiasBora  Sorry. I initially didn't see that you had revised mwe code in the OP. Thanks for doing that!

Comment: @SiuslawMath you also need to remove the `ed` in the `aligned` (see my edit, in my first answer I only fixed the indentation).

Comment: @toabiasBora   Yes, I now see ```align``` vs ```aligned```. What is causing the enumeration of the solution steps on the right side? Thank you!

Comment: @SiuslawMath if you don't want the enumeration on the right, you can use the star version `\begin{align*}…\end{align*}`. Enumeration is useful to refer to the equations later.

Comment: ah, yes, forget about ```{align*}```. For my high school algebra classes, usually I use enumeration to number each problem in the problem set. But your point is well taken!