# Pass part of halign body as an argument to macro (previously AMS align and its groups)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align

*I originally thought this had to do with the align environment but I discovered it's a feature of `\halign`, hence the major edit.*

When inside a tabular environment or simple halign, I need to be able to pass parts of it (spanning multiple columns and rows) to a macro which would process it and put it right back (for a simple example, place some delimiter on the right and left of the content). It works except when there is something typeset before the macro in the **same** cell. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1\bar{$\rightarrow$ #1 $\leftarrow$}

\begin{document}

\halign{ # & # \cr
  \foo foo & bar \bar \cr
%
  \foo foo & bar \cr
  foo & bar \bar \cr
%
  foo \foo foo \bar & \foo bar \bar \cr
%  foo \foo foo  & bar \bar \cr % error 'Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \foo'
}

\end{document}
```

Using a non-delimited macro like `\def\foo#1{ whathever #1}` I cannot span multiple rows (I can't pass it \cr even if I define it as `\long`). Can I achieve what I want using an environment, if so---how?

P.S. What I'm trying to do is find a flexible solution to put a fancy frame certain parts of equations inside an ams align environment and I decided to write my own in TikZ following @Marco Daniel's example in [How to box two lines inside align*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/how-to-box-two-lines-inside-align). In the end, I need to grab the whole content of the framed box (which may start anywhere within a cell, and span multiple cells and rows), so I can calculate it's height and depth properly.

Comment: Could you not use something like `tikzmark` here?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you're doing, so this may not be of any use. But you can use `tikzmark` to mark up points in maths or text and then overlay annotations in TikZ. For example, some simple frames:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,calc}
\def\bmarkeq#1\emarkeq{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \bmarkeq\tikzmark{a1} \underbrace{foobar}_{barbaz} & & foobar \tikzmark{a2}\emarkeq \\
  \bmarkeq\tikzmark{b1} \underbrace{foobar}_{barbaz\tikzmark{b3}} & & foobar \tikzmark{b2}\emarkeq foo \\
  foo & & \bmarkeq\tikzmark{c1} \underbrace{foobar}_{barbaz\tikzmark{c3}} & & foobar \tikzmark{c2}\emarkeq \\
  % typing any text BEFORE \bmarkeq in the SAME group/column fails
  % foo \bmarkeq \underbrace{foobar}_{barbaz} & & foobar \emarkeq \\
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \foreach \i in {a1,a2,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3} \coordinate (\i) at ({pic cs:\i});
  \node (a) [fit=(a1) (a2) (b1) (b2) (b3), draw=blue, inner xsep=5pt, inner ysep=7.5pt, yshift=5pt] {};
  \draw [magenta, inner sep=5pt] ($(c1)!1/2!(c1 |- b3)$) rectangle (c2 |- c3);
  \node (c) [fit=(a) (c1) (c2) (c3), draw=green, thick, rounded corners] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple framing]

Comment: This looks good, I tried defining separate \bmarkeq and \emarkeq to simply place numbered marks, but to get a box of a proper height, it requires placement of intermediate marks in order to get the position of the top and bottom of the equation. I want to grab the whole equation as an argument, so I can calculate its height and depth and do all the work from there, so in the end I would only need to do something like \bmarkeq <some tall equation, maybe more than 1 line> \emarkeq, which leads me to the original problem...