# Add Box to multiline-expression which is part of aligned-equation?

Tags: equations, box

I want to add a box (black color) to encapsulate the last two lines of this triple-line-aligned expression.

As you can see, the current solution inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/how-to-box-two-lines-inside-align) is not perfect because it misses some topmost components.

[image]

Note that the target is a *part* of the aligned-expression so the general commends like `boxed` or `empheq` may not work.

```
\newcommand{\pstrut}[1]{\vrule height0pt depth0pt width0pt #1 \fboxsep}
\newcommand*\bmarkeq{\stepcounter{markeq}%
  \tikz[remember picture]\node(startframe-\themarkeq){\pstrut{height}};%
  \kern\fboxsep}
\newcommand*\emarkeq{\kern\fboxsep
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node (endframe-\themarkeq){\pstrut{depth}};
    \draw[,black,opacity=0.8] (startframe-\themarkeq.north) 
      rectangle (endframe-\themarkeq.south);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{L}_{c}(\theta) 
    = &\sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln p\left(x_{i}, z_{i} ; \theta\right) \\
    = \bmarkeq &\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(z_{i}\left[\ln (\pi)+x_{i} \ln \left(p_{r}\right)+\left(1-x_{i}\right) \ln \left(1-p_{r}\right)\right] \\
    &+ \left(1-z_{i}\right)\left[\ln (1-\pi)+x_{i} \ln \left(p_{b}\right)+\left(1-x_{i}\right) \ln \left(1-p_{b}\right)\right]\right) \emarkeq
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need TiKZ to do that: `amsmath` has the `\boxed` command  and  `mathtools` adds the `\Aboxed` command, which may include the alignment points. Here are two suggestions to do that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{L}_{c}(\theta)
    &=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln p(x_{i}, z_{i} ; \theta) \\
   & =\boxed{\begin{aligned}[t] &\sum_{i=1}^{m}\bigl(z_{i}\bigl[\ln (\pi)+x_{i} \ln (p_{r})+(1-x_{i}) \ln(1-p_{r})\bigr]\\
   &+(1-z_{i})\bigl[\ln (1-\pi)+x_{i} \ln(p_{b})+(1-x_{i}) \ln(1-p_{b})\bigr]\bigr)\end{aligned}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{L}_{c}(\theta)
    &=\sum_{i=1}^{m} \ln p(x_{i}, z_{i} ; \theta) \\
\Aboxed{& ={\begin{aligned}[t]&\sum_{i=1}^{m}\bigl(z_{i}\bigl[\ln (\pi)+x_{i} \ln (p_{r})+(1-x_{i}) \ln(1-p_{r})\bigr]\\
   &+(1-z_{i})\bigl[\ln (1-\pi)+x_{i} \ln(p_{b})+(1-x_{i}) \ln(1-p_{b})\bigr]\bigr)\end{aligned}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]